# Compile scope dependency which is runtime when project is a dependency

Tags: gradle

I have Project A which has a dependency on a library (Jackson as an example). When I include Project A as a compile-time dependency of Project B, I'd like the library to be included as a runtime only dependency so that it isn't available to the developer of Project B to use directly.

What is the accepted way to achieve this using Gradle?

Comment: How do you plan to include project A into project B? As a simple project dependency (so that B is a child or sibling of A) or as a module dependency via some Maven/Ivy repository?

Comment: It's a simple project dependency.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `compileOnly` configuration in Project A; it is not transitive, so will not be available to Project B. But this also means, that it will need to be listed as Project B's runtime dependency.

[Official intro for Compile-Only Dependencies](https://blog.gradle.org/introducing-compile-only-dependencies)

Comment: I was hoping for a solution that involves some configuration in Project A given it "knows" what the dependencies need to be

Comment: You could try to add the dependency in project A as both a `compileOnly` and a `runtime` dependency.

Comment: @lu.koerfer, how would that help?

Comment: @Cheetah, Project A knows its own dependencies and can control whether it will be available to Project B. This is achieved with compile/compileOnly/runtime configuration. Project B can also 'reduce' the amount of transitive deps (disable all transitive deps or exclude some). So, if you hid it from B in A, B needs to restore it.

Comment: It would appear that `compileOnly` + `runtimeOnly` together work! - thanks for the idea! Is there anyway I can create my own scope and have it extend from these two so I don't have to continually specify the dependencies